# How to hide a particular form field on selecting a field from a drop down in php not in javascript or jquery?

Tags: php

How to hide a particular form field on selecting a field from a drop down in php only not in javascript or jquery please help me?

Answer (score 2):

My friend perhaps you are forgetting what is php and what is javascript..

When you ask for a page from a server it runs the php ie server scripting file on the server and return a result containing html, css, javascript. Which are responsible for scripting on client-side..

Now you are asking to do some operation in client page from server script without even calling a server script..

The only way of calling the php ie server script is either you submit the form by selecting your option in dropdown..or by ajax...As Both of them are not possible without any client side script..Its not possible..

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server side language, so execution is already finished by the time the page is sent to the user. You would either need to have them submit the page after they've made their selection or use a client side language (like JS).

Comment: i want that as soon as user select petadoption field from dropdown then price field from form is hidden.

Comment: That's not going to happen in PHP. You could have them select petadoption and submit, then reload the same page with the price field displayed, or you're going to have to use JS.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot done without JS (jQuery is JS...).

Why wouldn't you use JS?